# attachEvent vs addEventListener vs none

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var listenjustonce function(callback){ 
window.top.removeEventListener("mousemove",listenjustonce );}

window.top.attachEvent("mousemove", listenjustonce ); //or OnMouseMove?:D
window.top.mousemove = listenjustonce;
window.top.addEventListener("mousemove",listenjustonce );
```

which of the 3 should be kept/removed?
http://caniuse.com/#search=addEventListener

Actually, anyone bookmarked a table with all the different event-name variants or should I make one?

Comment: The one on the bottom and the one on the top. `remove/addEventListener  ` can be used by all major browsers and they are recommended above all other ways of event handling in plain JavaScript.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, [MDN's list of event types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: Primary opinion based?

Comment: thank you Jonathan!  The MDN list doesnt cover onmousemove, althought it also works as html attribute i think. 
- So, (if the 3 lines needed to be as analogous as possible, then) the 3 event names need to be what? ( if not  onmousemove,  mousemove,  mousemove)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three kinda-sorta do the same thing

Of them, this method is often called the `DOM0` method and it predates any actual standards:

window.top.mousemove = listenjustonce;

This method works but has several major disadvantages:

- You can't easily *stack* them -- have multiple listeners
- You can't remove a single listener from a stack.
- Garbage collection bugs in older browsers.

`attachEvent` was Microsoft's method -- and I believe that it predates any standards as well.  For years it was the best way to attach events onto IE, but it is no longer needed in modern development.

`addEventListener` is the best way to attach events and is fully supported now.  Modern programming should always use this.

When `attachEvent` was commonly used, it was normal to use a wrapper to choose between `attachEvent` and `addEventListener`, based upon which one was available.  Some of these wrappers could even properly preserve the `this` value, which is often lost with `attachEvent`.

Comment: It's good to note that `attachEvent` does not exist anywhere but IE, so it's a must to check if the method exists before using it.

Comment: I added another reason `on*` can be bad, especially in older IE, where JS and DOM garbage collection are unaware of each other and memory leaks are easy. IE8 is officially EOL, so just use `addEventListener` unless you are catering to old, unpatched browsers.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderO'Mara -- I had forgotten about that.